# $\frac{1}{7\operatorname{cosec}^{2}(7\theta)}{\sum_{k=0}^{6} \operatorname{cosec}^{2}(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{7})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

Here, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$. This question is from a book recommended for preparing for the JEE Advance exam.
I tried converting the series like, $$\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{7})}=\frac{2}{1-\cos(2\theta+\frac{2k\pi}{7})}$$
But this didn't lead to anything.
Then I also tried taking the $k=0$ term out and pair up first and last terms which still didn't lead to anything.
This looks like a very interesting problem and help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use elements in the titles of questions which will stretch the vertical space.  Also, please include the question you are trying to answer in the body of your question.  Finally, please review the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/) for the site---Math SE is not a place to simply post problems with the expectation that others will solve them for you.